# Google maps don't work if APK is installed via Google Play

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I have Android app with Google maps.

Debug and Release versions of APK works fine if I build and install it directly to phone.

But when I install the APK from Google Play (Alpha or Beta testing), maps are not shown (blank screen).

I have of course API key in release XML file and so on...I cannot understand, why same APK is okay, if I install it directly to phone and maps is not shown if this APK is installed via Google Play.

Any advise?

Comment: Get SHA from signed key and add this SHA to google console and try.

Comment: It is done. SHA is added to Google console. I think, if it is not done, release version will never show maps (but it works, if I install APK directly to phone and doesn't via Google Play~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. Somebody from our team enabled (accepted) "Google Play App Signing" for this app  [(see more here)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en). So adding SHA from Google Play Console to Google Console (API key) solved this problem.