# Maps activity error when installed by play store

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I've built an app with multiplies activities and one of these activies is a map activity. The problem is that when I install the app-release.apk generated by android studio directly the map works perfectly but when I install it using play store it only shows a gray screen. Does anyone knows how can i fix it?

I have installed directly by apk and undirectly using the play store, but the map only load when I install it directly. I have already removed the location permission, because my app only show some places and the user location is not needed.

there's no error message, but a gray screen is displayed and the map can't be loaded.

Comment: Temporarily add very explicit exception logging. Surround as much code as you can with `try{ ... } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` to see what's causing the problem and avoid some exception being swallowed.

Comment: Also this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943261/google-maps-dont-work-if-apk-is-installed-via-google-play